# join 2 DF with diferent dimension scala

Tags: scala

Hi I have 2 Differente DF

```
scala> d1.show()               scala> d2.show()
+--------+-------+             +--------+----------+
|   fecha|eventos|             |   fecha|TotalEvent|
+--------+-------+             +--------+----------+
|20180404|      3|             |       0|     23534|
|20180405|      7|             |20180322|        10|
|20180406|     10|             |20180326|        50|
|20180409|      4|             |20180402|         6|
....                           |20180403|       118|
scala> d1.count()              |20180404|      1110|
res3: Long = 60                 ...
                               scala> d2.count()
                               res7: Long = 74
```

But I like to join them by `fecha` without loose data, and then, create a new column with a math operation (TotalEvent - eventos)*100/TotalEvent

Something like this:

```
+---------+-------+----------+--------+
|fecha    |eventos|TotalEvent|  KPI   |
+---------+-------+----------+--------+
|        0|       |    23534 |  100.00|
| 20180322|       |       10 |  100.00|
| 20180326|       |       50 |  100.00|
| 20180402|       |        6 |  100.00|
| 20180403|       |      118 |  100.00|
| 20180404|     3 |     1110 |   99.73|
| 20180405|     7 |     1204 |   99.42|
| 20180406|    10 |     1526 |   99.34|
| 20180407|       |       14 |  100.00|
| 20180409|     4 |     1230 |   99.67|
| 20180410|    11 |     1456 |   99.24|
| 20180411|     6 |     1572 |   99.62|
| 20180412|     5 |     1450 |   99.66|
| 20180413|     7 |     1214 |   99.42|
 .....
```

The problems is that I can't find the way to do it.
When I use:

```
scala> d1.join(d2,d2("fecha").contains(d1("fecha")), "left").show()
```

I loose the data that isn't in both table.

```
+--------+-------+--------+----------+
|   fecha|eventos|   fecha|TotalEvent|
+--------+-------+--------+----------+
|20180404|      3|20180404|      1110|
|20180405|      7|20180405|      1204|
|20180406|     10|20180406|      1526|
|20180409|      4|20180409|      1230|
|20180410|     11|20180410|      1456|
 ....
```

Additional, How can I add a new column with the math operation?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `left`-joining `df2` with `df1` and calculating `KPI` based on whether `eventos` is null or not in the joined dataset (using `when/otherwise`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq(
  ("20180404", 3),
  ("20180405", 7),
  ("20180406", 10),
  ("20180409", 4)
).toDF("fecha", "eventos")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("0", 23534),
  ("20180322", 10),
  ("20180326", 50),
  ("20180402", 6),
  ("20180403", 118),
  ("20180404", 1110),
  ("20180405", 100),
  ("20180406", 100)
).toDF("fecha", "TotalEvent")

df2.
  join(df1, Seq("fecha"), "left_outer").
  withColumn( "KPI", 
    round( when($"eventos".isNull, 100.0).
      otherwise(($"TotalEvent" - $"eventos") * 100.0 / $"TotalEvent"),
      2
    )
  ).show
// +--------+----------+-------+-----+
// |   fecha|TotalEvent|eventos|  KPI|
// +--------+----------+-------+-----+
// |       0|     23534|   null|100.0|
// |20180322|        10|   null|100.0|
// |20180326|        50|   null|100.0|
// |20180402|         6|   null|100.0|
// |20180403|       118|   null|100.0|
// |20180404|      1110|      3|99.73|
// |20180405|       100|      7| 93.0|
// |20180406|       100|     10| 90.0|
// +--------+----------+-------+-----+
```

Note that if the more precise raw `KPI` is wanted instead, just remove the wrapping `round( , 2)`.

Comment: or use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.round` to format `KPI`

Comment: @Raphael Roth, a rounded numeric column is likely more useful to keep than a formatted string.  Answer updated with your suggestion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in several of steps. First join, then select the calculated column, then fill in the na:

```
@ val df2a = df2.withColumnRenamed("fecha", "fecha2")  # to avoid ambiguous column names after the join

@ val df3 = df1.join(df2a, df1("fecha") === df2a("fecha2"), "outer")

@ val kpi = df3.withColumn("KPI", (($"TotalEvent" - $"eventos") / $"TotalEvent" * 100 as "KPI")).na.fill(100, Seq("KPI"))

@ kpi.show()
+--------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------+
|   fecha|eventos|  fecha2|TotalEvent|              KPI|
+--------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------+
|    null|   null|20180402|         6|            100.0|
|    null|   null|       0|     23534|            100.0|
|    null|   null|20180322|        10|            100.0|
|20180404|      3|20180404|      1110|99.72972972972973|
|20180406|     10|    null|      null|            100.0|
|    null|   null|20180403|       118|            100.0|
|    null|   null|20180326|        50|            100.0|
|20180409|      4|    null|      null|            100.0|
|20180405|      7|    null|      null|            100.0|
+--------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problems with mixed both suggestion recived.

```
val dfKPI=d1.join(right=d2, usingColumns = Seq("cliente","fecha"), "outer").orderBy("fecha").withColumn( "KPI",round( when($"eventos".isNull, 100.0).otherwise(($"TotalEvent" - $"eventos") * 100.0 / $"TotalEvent"),2))
```